# TSP heuristics for limited distance information

Tags: algorithms, graphs, optimization, heuristics, traveling-salesman

this is my first question on ComputerScience beta. :)

I've posted a similiar [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207012/tsp-heuristics-for-limited-distance-information) on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) and a friendly user advised me to post my question on this site.

**Problem:**

> I'm looking for TSP heuristics in the case of limited information about the edges, for example: I have $n$ nodes but can only ask for $~\sim4n$ distances. My graphs are metrically and I can make an estimate in advance with the euclidean distance, but those estimates might be very bad.

**Question:**

> So what are the TSP-Heuristika for those distance-matrices?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "My graphs are metrically"? Does it mean that if you have $dist(a,b)$ and $dist(b,c)$ then $dist(a,c) \le dist(a,b) + dist(b,c)$ (triangle inequlaity)?

Comment: By 'metrically' i do not mean the euclidean distance.

Comment: You mentioned euclidean distance in your question... Anyway, you have to describe your class of graphs very precisely. May be you should insert some word after the "metrically"

Comment: Also posted on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/q/207012/37212), and on [CSTheory.SE](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31537/5038) and [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1289818/14578).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted. If you don't get a satisfying answer after a week or so, feel free to flag for migration.

Comment: I am closing this question (even though it is on-topic) because it has [also been posted on Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/31537/tsp-heuristics-for-limited-distance-information) and is answered there.